# Running Tkinter programs on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to complete this tutorial https://likegeeks.com/python-gui-examples-tkinter-tutorial/amp/.

I have the following code written

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

window.title('Welcome to LikeGeeks app')

window.mainloop()
```

I have run the command

```
sudo apt install python3-tk
```

However I am still getting the following error:

```
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined
```

The Python version on my machine is Python 3.6.5.

Turtle graphics work fine.

edit: I renamed the file from tkinter.py to test.py and I got this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
from tkinter import *
ImportError: bad magic number in 'tkinter': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
```

Comment: I navigated to the folder the file is located in. I type python 3 scriptname.py. I also tried the ./. No cigar.

Comment: It looks like you executed your `python3` with `python2` by typing `python 3 scriptname.py`. Instead remove the space between `python` and `3`: `python3 scriptname.py`. Otherwise see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514371/whats-the-bad-magic-number-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to SteelDriver for figuring this out. The file should not be named tkinter.py.

It gave me a traceback and I was able to google it and a .pyc file was causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually strange. The `import` statement works fine (or at least doesn't raise an exception), but instead `Tk()` is not found.
The only thing I can come up with is trying to run

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()

window.title('Welcome to LikeGeeks app')

window.mainloop()
```